# Html tags and script inserted in the kml is not working on google maps

Tags: jquery, google-maps, kml

I am new to KML and google maps. I have a KML with an image, which is hosted on google. When I load the KML through the html, I am able to get the image on the google maps.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
        <Folder>
            <Document>
                <Placemark>
                    <name>ABC</name>
                    <description><![CDATA[<html>
                       <body>
                           <img src="https://sites.google.com/.../image1.JPG" height="100" />
                           <p>some text</p>
                        </body>
                     </html>]]></description>
                   <Point>
                      <coordinates>xx.xxxx,yy.yyyy,zzz</coordinates>
                   </Point>
              </Placemark>
           </Document>
        </Folder>
        </kml>
```

Now I want to zoom this image. I found a script which zooms the image

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/wp-content/themes/radial/jquery.elevatezoom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <body>
        <img id="zoom_01" src="image1.JPG" height="100" data-zoom-image="image1.JPG"/> 
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#zoom_01").elevateZoom(); 
            }); 
        </script>
    </body>
</head>
</html>
```

I have tested the above script. It works well. Now I am trying insert the above script inside the kml `description` tag.

```
<description><![CDATA[<html>
  <body>
    <img id="zoom_01" src="https://sites.google.com/.../image1.JPG" height="100" data-zoom-image="https://sites.google.com/.../image1.JPG"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#zoom_01").elevateZoom(); 
            }); 
        </script>
    <p>some text</p>

  </body>
</html>]]></description>
```

But the above code does not zooms the image on the google maps when I move the mouse over the image. I inspected the html of the image on the google crome and found that image on the google maps has no `id` tag nor the `data-zoom-image` tag. Also script is missing in the html.

1. Any idea why I am not getting the tags and scripts corresponding to image even after mentioning it inside the `description` tag of the kml?
2. If putting the scripts inside the `description` tag of the kml is not the correct method to implement the zoom functionality, then how can I implement the zoom functionality of the image on the google maps?

Comment: Please give a valid reason before voting down the question. I tried to ask the question as clear as possible... so please mention the reason for voting down the question

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/kmllayer):

> `<description>` | yes(supported) | HTML content is allowed but is sanitized to protect
>   from cross-browser attacks. Entity replacements of the form
>   $[dataName] are not supported.

Your javascript is removed to "sanitize the HTML".

To work around that (depending on how complex your KML is), you could look at loading the KML with a third party KML parser.

[Working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_simpleMap_geoxml3_imageZoom.html) that uses [geoxml3](https://github.com/geocodezip/geoxml3)

I had to remove the `$(document).ready`, add a event listener that listened for the `domready` event on the `InfoWindow` and change the HTML in the KML to add a class to the image to be zoomed (I assumed you wanted to do this to more than one image).

javascript in the HTML page:

```
var map;
var infowindow;
function initialize() {
   map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'));
   infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    geo = new geoXML3.parser({
        map: map,
        zoom: true,
        singleInfoWindow: true,
        infoWindow: infowindow,
    });
    geo.parse("http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kml/SO_KmlWithJavascript_20170122.kml");
    google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'domready', function() {
      $(".zoom_img").elevateZoom(); 
    });
}
```

KML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
 <Folder>
  <Document>
   <Placemark>
    <name>ABC</name>
    <description><![CDATA[<html>
     <body>
      <img class="zoom_img" src="http://www.geocodezip.com/images/world.png" height="100" data-zoom-image="http://www.geocodezip.com/images/world.png"/>
      <p>some text</p>
     </body>
    </html>]]></description>
    <Point>
     <coordinates>-72,42,0</coordinates>
    </Point>
   </Placemark>
  </Document>
 </Folder>
</kml>
```